# PHP highest directory

Tags: php, include, directory

Sorry to bother you over something so trivial. I can't word the question properly to get a result on any search bar, I've tried google, and here, but got no related answers.

I'm currently setting up an include statement, and PHP files from different folders need to include the same files, namely "(Top directory)/public_html/Include/Head.php".

I'm not sure how to tell PHP to look for public_html in the top directory. I originally thought that was what ".." was for, but it seems to behave wierdly. Can somone please explain?

Here's what I'm using:

```
<?php include("../public_html/Include/Head.php") ?>
```

Also, include is a folder where I put all the files that users generally don't need to view, mainly to get them out of the way, and make my main folder less messy.

Comment: `..` just moves up a level in the directory tree. For your sample, if you're in `/x/y/z`, then the include will be looking for `/x/y/Include/Header.php`

Comment: Would you be able to use `..` more than once in a link? Such as `../../Include`?

Comment: Yes, though at some point you'll reach the top of the file system and then any extra `../` will be ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could prepend with the doc root so that you have a consistent starting point and won't have to worry about traversing in your particular case, e.g.,

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/Include/Head.php')
```

or, for an application-wide solution, you could simply add `Include` to your include path:

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/Include');
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php

Comment: I'm getting this error from the Document_Root method: 

`Warning: include() [function.include]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File (/usr/local/apache/htdocs/public_html/Include/SQLFunctions.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/:/usr/lib/php:/tmp) in /home/a7077395/public_html/Include/Head.php on line 2`. 

I'm not entirely sure what it means to be perfectly honest. If it helps, I know this is the Document_Root: `/usr/local/apache/htdocs`, and this is the include_path: `.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php`

Comment: Definitely contact your webhost company to see why this is the case. They should be setting a correct document root for you in your VirtualHost config. From your warning, your doc root appears to be `/home/a7077395/public_html`. If they can't set it to that in the config file, simply create a `DOC_ROOT` define and set it to `/home/a7077395/public_html` and use that in place of `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` and/or place it in your include path.

Answer (score 3):

Define some global constant: `define('TOP_DIR', '/www/')` then use that in all your includes:

`include(TOP_DIR.'public_html/Include/Head.php');`

Put that `define()` in some easy to reach location and include it on any page you need.  This stuff becomes much simpler if you use a framework that always has a single entry point like CodeIgniter.  Then you can just have a file of constants and settings you include in your entry point file and you know that those things will always be available.

Comment: Thanks, I assumed there'd be a way of getting the top directory without using a method like this, but if not, this seems like the best thing.

Comment: @Ashley Davies webbiedave's solution is pretty good too, it's just a different way to get to the document root effectively.  Full paths are always going to treat you better than relative paths and will be much easier to debug when something fails.  My solution is more generally applicable when you start working with libraries outside your document root.

Answer (score 2):

PHP's file importing is a bit weird, if you want to import relative to the file you want, use this instead:

```
<?php include(dirname(__FILE__) . "../Include/Head.php") ?>
```

The reason is that if you have a file in `(Top directory)/public_html/myfile.php` that includes this file, the relative includes will be relative to `myfile.php` and not the included file.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things which affect what you're trying to accomplish.

First, absolute and relative paths. Any time you see directory navigation shortcuts in a path, you're working with a relative path. `..` means to go *up* a directory, or to the parent directory.

Second, the concept of rooting or chrooting may apply. Depending on your system, the topmost directory `/` (or `\`) may or may not be where you are serving files from. As an example, you can set the topmost folder of a particular web site to be a specific folder in your filesystem (using Apache). This is considered "rooting" the web site to that folder. No user or browser can "see" files from its parent folders.

PHP, however, generally is not rooted to the same location as the web site.

If your PHP files are in multiple levels of folder, yet you need them to all include files from the same location, then you may want to use absolute paths.

The specifics of what your path should be are entirely system dependent.